# time out when clicking an element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an issue when trying to click a link text. The problem is the page load too long and it causes an exception : "Command duration or timeout: 60.01 seconds". I also set :

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It's always time out in 60.01 seconds, look like code can't overwrite the default time out of pageload. I'm using chrome driver. Here is my code :

```
    driver.get(baseUrl + "?k=" + test.Key);

    // verify the MoCoin icon exists
    assertTrue("The 'MoCoin' icon does not exist",
            driver.findElements(By.id("tokens-navbar")).size() != 0);

    // verify the 'pronews' menu exists
    assertTrue("The the 'pronews' menu does not exist", driver
            .findElements(By.linkText("PRONEWS")).size() != 0);

    // click on the 'pronews' menu
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("PRONEWS")).click(); // exception here, the element was clicked and the new page was loading
```

Is there any way to overwrite the time out of pageload ? Or any trick to stop the page load so i can verify the title and other elements ? Any help would be greate.

Comment: I have this same issue. I'd love to know the answer if you found it.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I have done to overcome this issue. I have used [Appium](http://appium.io/) for automation testing and I just set the time out for this application more than 60 seconds. The issue is not belong to web driver. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try using explicit wait instead of implicit wait: 
Explicit wait :

`WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element)` : you can also ignore exceptions here.

Implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

more info here : http://www.bizalgo.com/2012/01/14/timing-races-selenium-2-implicit-waits-explicit-waits/

Have a look at fluent wait also : http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Comment: the element was clicked and new page was loading. After 60 seconds it caused time out exception. It's not about the driver can't find the element.

Comment: oh, sorry for mis-interpreting the question. Try setting driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS) before implicit wait. See if that works.

Comment: thanks for your support but it's still time out in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to wait for 7 seconds with a polling time of 50 ms - Change the time as per your convenience -

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,7,50).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.linkText("PRONEWS"), "PRONEWS"));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("PRONEWS")).click();
```

Comment: the element was clicked and new page was loading. After 60 seconds it caused time out exception. It's not about the driver can't find the element.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question - Sorry I couldn't be of much help. Looks like you have ran into these 2 issues -    https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=9 AND https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=211